# Add new element to imported xsl with stylsheet

Tags: xml, xslt, import

**Problem:**
I have  a demo.xsl and a demo2.xsl.  I can't modify the demo.xsl, and i need to add new element (country) inside the "number". So I import the demo.xsl and i'm stuck. How can i continue? How can I insert a new tag?

**demo.xsl output:**

```xml
   <cars color="green">
      <brand>Suzuki</brand>
      <number>ASD-653</number>
   </cars>
```

**demo2.xsl expected output:**

```xml
   <cars color="green">
      <brand>Suzuki</brand>
      <number>ASD-653</number>
         <country>ROM</country>
   </cars>
```

**demo.xsl:**

```xml
 <xsl:template match="cars[@element-type='recordset']/record">
    <cars>
      <xsl:attribute name="color">
        <xsl:value-of select="color" />
      </xsl:attribute>
      <brand>
        <xsl:value-of select="brand" />
      </brandr>    
      <number>
        <xsl:value-of select="number" />
      </number>
    </cars>
  </xsl:template>
```

**demo2.xsl:**

```xml
 <xsl:import href="demo.xsl" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to add a transformation step:

```
<xsl:template match="cars[@element-type='recordset']/record">
  <xsl:variable name="import-result">
     <xsl:apply-imports/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:apply-templates select="$import-result/node()" mode="add"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()" mode="add">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
   </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="cars" mode="add">
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
      <country>ROM</country>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

To be able to use `<xsl:apply-templates select="$import-result/node()" mode="add"/>` you need an XSLT 2 processor or an XSLT 1 processor not requiring an extension to convert a variable with a result tree fragment into a nodeset; as most XSLT 1 processor require an extension functions for them you would need to change that line to

```
<xsl:apply-templates xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" select="exsl:node-set($import-result)/node()" mode="add"/>
```

If the value of the `country` element depends on data (e.g. child or attribute) in the original `record` then you could pass that on in the apply-templates (e.g. for a `country` attribute of `record`)

```
<xsl:apply-templates select="$import-result/node()" mode="add">
  <xsl:with-param name="country" select="@country"/>
</xsl:apply-templates>
```

and use it with

```
<xsl:template match="cars" mode="add">
   <xsl:param name="country"/>
   <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()" mode="#current"/>
      <country>
         <xsl:value-of select="$country"/>
      </country>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's working with some modification.

Answer (score 1):

This is why it's not a good idea to use such "brick" template style like:

```
  <xsl:template match="cars[@element-type='recordset']/record">
    <cars color="{color}">
      <brand>
        <xsl:value-of select="brand" />
      </brandr>    
      <number>
        <xsl:value-of select="number" />
      </number>
    </cars>
  </xsl:template>
```

The XSLT extension mechanism, like in any language with "inheritance", may act over the result of the "super class" to further process (even a second pass transformation as proposed by [Martin Honnen's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55867556/11102282)). But if you use this pull style in the imported stylesheet:

```
  <xsl:template match="cars[@element-type='recordset']/record">
    <cars color="{color}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </cars>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record/brand|record/number">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record/*"/>
```

Then you could just add to the applied stylesheet

```
  <xsl:template match="cars[@element-type='recordset']/record">
    <cars color="{color}">
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
      <country>ROM</country>
    </cars>
  </xsl:template>
```

Or if the `country` element could be the result of another child of `record`, you would need a simple rule as:

```
  <xsl:template match="record/country">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>
```